# How should cardinality be understood in a table with a compound key?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, database-design

I am learning about database structuring and when watching the following [video](https://youtu.be/jshi9VCTm7g?t=669) I cannot identify if there is a cardinality between the *ENVIO*, *PEDIDO* and *PRODUCTO* tables?

[image]

If it is clear to me that there is an N: N cardinality between *PEDIDOS* AND *PRODUCTOS* and I understand the information you want to record in the *ENVIO* table, **what is not clear to me is if there is any cardinality between this table and the other two mentioned.**

Is the diagram in the image correct (is the notation "crow's feet" being used)?
If it is incorrect how should I modify the diagram to correctly express the cardinality between the meted tables?

*NOTE:
the ORDER(PEDIDO) table can have several PRODUCT(PRODUCTO) associated and each PRODUCT only belongs to one ORDER.
In parallel, the shipments of each order must be registered, for which the SHIPMENTS(ENVIO) table was created (which has as foreign keys the primary keys of the ORDERS AND PRODUCT tables)*

Comment: The crows feet notation seems to contradict the cardinality implied by the use of pedido.productoId as a FK.

Comment: You should definitely separate out the lines as its impossible to know what one relationship hidden under the other might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the English terms for your tables...

There is **not** a many-to-many relationship between ORDER and PRODUCT.  Each order has only one product, because ORDER.Product_ID depends on ORDER.Order_Number (the primary key of ORDER).  I would say that the crows foot notation in your diagram doesn't agree with the column definitions.

This means that ORDER to PRODUCT is **many to one**.

Secondly, SHIPMENT has one ORDER and one PRODUCT per SHIPMENT.Shipment_ID.  This means that each ORDER will have one SHIPMENT (which is also for one PRODUCT).  A PRODUCT would (eventually) have many SHIPMENTs across various ORDERs.

Your question mentions a compound key, but each of these tables has a single column primary key according to your diagram.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, regarding the title, I was wrong when uploading the correct image (I will create another question to clarify another part of my doubt). But I did understand the reason for using a primary key for the SHIPMENT table.